# Are the ideals in two GNS constructions linked to the equivalence (or not) of the CCR representations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, representation-theory, density-operator

Starting from the abstract C* algebra $A$ of canonical commutative relations, a state $\rho$ over this algebra enables to construct a Hilbert space $A/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of the elements $a$ such that $\rho (a^* a) = 0 $. the vacuum in this space depends on the equivalence class of $\rho$.
I read that in the case of infinite degrees of freedom, many inequivalent representations can be built by this construction. 
I wonder how the inequivalence of the representations depends on properties of these ideals (or not).